# ¿Cómo quitar el cuadrado blanco producto de los márgenes en mi vista de mi proyecto Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, aplicación-movil, margin

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de Flutter donde tengo un fondo principal con un gradiente lineal de dos colores. En esta pantalla, quiero mostrar dos contenedores tipo input text para que los usuarios ingresen su correo electrónico y contraseña.

El problema que estoy enfrentando es que al aplicar márgenes a los contenedores para que no queden pegados al borde de la pantalla, los márgenes se vuelven blancos en lugar de mostrar el fondo principal con el gradiente de colores.

Intenté envolver los contenedores en un `Material` y establecer un color de fondo transparente, pero no logro que funcione correctamente. Los contenedores siguen mostrando un fondo blanco en lugar del fondo principal.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme a solucionar este problema y hacer que los contenedores tengan márgenes sin afectar el fondo principal con el gradiente de colores?

¡Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double baseWidth = 375;
    double fem = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / baseWidth;
    double ffem = fem * 0.97;
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Container(
        // loginxkk (2:14)
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration (
          gradient: LinearGradient (
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            colors: <Color>[Color(0xffffecd0), Color(0xfff3b353)],
            stops: <double>[0, 1],
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              // vector1oWU (2:22)
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0*fem, 0*fem, 285*fem, 6*fem),
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Scene()));
                },
                style: TextButton.styleFrom (
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                ),
                child: Container(
                  width: 17*fem,
                  height: 34*fem,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/page-1/images/vector-1-wba.png',
                    width: 17*fem,
                    height: 34*fem,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              // karpicentrologo1tXv (2:21)
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(9*fem, 0*fem, 0*fem, 42*fem),
              width: 293*fem,
              height: 291*fem,
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/page-1/images/karpicentro-logo-1.png',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              // correoCoW (2:16)
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0*fem, 0*fem, 208*fem, 2*fem),
              child: Text(
                'Correo',
                style: SafeGoogleFont (
                  'Inter',
                  fontSize: 16*ffem,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  height: 1.2125*ffem/fem,
                  color: Color(0xff000000),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Material(
              child: Container(
                // rectangle16dz (2:15)
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8*fem, 0*fem, 0*fem, 20*fem),
                width: 294*fem,
                height: 55*fem,
                decoration: BoxDecoration (
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15*fem),
                  color: Color(0xffffffff),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Color(0x3f000000),
                      offset: Offset(0*fem, 4*fem),
                      blurRadius: 2*fem,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: 'Ingresa tu correo',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16 * fem, vertical: 16 * fem),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              // contraseaPNC (2:20)
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0*fem, 0*fem, 170*fem, 2*fem),
              child: Text(
                'Contraseña',
                style: SafeGoogleFont (
                  'Inter',
                  fontSize: 16*ffem,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  height: 1.2125*ffem/fem,
                  color: Color(0xff000000),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Material(
              child: Container(
                // rectangle2VAL (2:17)
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8*fem, 0*fem, 0*fem, 49*fem),
                width: 294*fem,
                height: 55*fem,
                decoration: BoxDecoration (
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15*fem),
                  color: Color(0xffffffff),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Color(0x3f000000),
                      offset: Offset(0*fem, 4*fem),
                      blurRadius: 2*fem,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: 'Ingresa tu contraseña',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16 * fem, vertical: 16 * fem),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              // autogroupsq7nC4k (WkFdzCmYGX9HjVD5y9sQ7n)
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(77*fem, 0*fem, 69*fem, 0*fem),
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 55*fem,
              decoration: BoxDecoration (
                color: Color(0xfff8a72c),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15*fem),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Color(0x3f000000),
                    offset: Offset(0*fem, 4*fem),
                    blurRadius: 2*fem,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: TextButton(
                // karpicentrologo2DRN (5:62)
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AgregarProducto()));
                },
                style: TextButton.styleFrom (
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Iniciar Sesión',
                    style: SafeGoogleFont (
                      'Inter',
                      fontSize: 16*ffem,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      height: 1.2125*ffem/fem,
                      color: Color(0xff000000),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
          );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es una posible solución solo agrégale la propiedad color al material y que sea de tipo transparente

```
 Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Container(
            margin:
                EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8 * fem, 0 * fem, 0 * fem, 20 * fem),
            width: 294 * fem,
            height: 55 * fem,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15 * fem),
              color: Color(0xffffffff),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Color(0x3f000000),
                  offset: Offset(0 * fem, 4 * fem),
                  blurRadius: 2 * fem,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: 'Ingresa tu correo',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 16 * fem, vertical: 16 * fem),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Excelente, intente usar esa propiedad pero cuando el contenedor era de tipo Container y no Material, por eso no funcionaba, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías envolver el Container que envuelve a tu textfield, dentro de otro container donde apliques margins necesarios.

```
             Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    8 * fem, 0 * fem, 0 * fem, 49 * fem),
                child: Container(
                  width: 294 * fem,
                  height: 55 * fem,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15 * fem),
                    color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: const Color(0x3f000000),
                        offset: Offset(0 * fem, 4 * fem),
                        blurRadius: 2 * fem,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: 'Ingresa tu contraseña',
                      hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 16 * fem, vertical: 16 * fem),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

Comment: Ya lo solucione, igualmente gracias, parece que también funcionaria tu método pero aclarando cambiar el Container por Material pues si no es este ultimo, lanza un error de Material Widget not found